# Physical Address in JAVA

Tags: java, macos

How do I get the physical addresses of my machine in **Java**?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which address? The memory address? IPv4 (or IPv6) address? MAC address?

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 6, java.net.NetworkInterface class now has the method getHardwareAddress()

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress()

If that's too new, there are UUID packages which try various methods per OS to ask for it.  Try e.g. http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/java/MAC-address-lookup-using-Java.html

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

    // Get IP Address
    byte[] ipAddr = addr.getAddress();

    // Get hostname
    String hostname = addr.getHostName();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
}
```

Comment: This is the IP address, not the physical (MAC) address.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for, in the Java API for the InetAddress class: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

```
getLocalHost()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need you need the MAC address you are going to require JNI. I use a library called [JUG](http://jug.safehaus.org/) to generate UUIDs based using the real MAC address of the machine. You can consult their [source code](http://jug.safehaus.org/curr/jug-src.zip) to see how this is accomplished on Linux, Solaris, Windows and Mac platforms.